# Replace arrays of function pointers using templates in modern c++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, c++17

I have some legacy code using arrays of function pointers in order to emulate  memory handlers.
So I'm now trying to have the same functionality using templates.
Here's what I tried so far :

```
template <typename R, typename ...ARGS> using function = R(*)(ARGS...);
template<size_t Size> using ReadType    = function<SizedUInt<Size>, const uint32_t>;

// arrays to redeclare
std::array<ReadType<8>,   memory_handler_size> read_8_handler_;
std::array<ReadType<16>,  memory_handler_size> read_16_handler_;
std::array<ReadType<32>,  memory_handler_size> read_32_handler_;

template<size_t Size>
void initializeReadHandler(uint32_t begin,
                           uint32_t end,
                           ReadType<Size> func) {
    begin >>= 16;
    end >>= 16;
    for (uint32_t current = begin; current <= end; ++current) {
         //read_handler_[current & 0xFFFF] = func;
    }
}
```

How can I declare the read handler arrays in order to initialize them using the templated `initializeReadHandler()` function ?
I don't want to use `std::function` as I can't afford the performance overhead ...

**... EDIT ...**
Here's the code based on Yakk's answer, max66 remarks, and some little fixes (typo, etc.):

```
template <typename R, typename ...ARGS> using function = R(*)(ARGS...);
template<size_t S> using ReadType    = function<SizedUInt<S>, const uint32_t>;

template<class ReadType>
using ReadHandlerType = std::array<ReadType, memory_handler_size>;

ReadHandler<8> read_8_handler_;
ReadHandler<16> read_16_handler_;
ReadHandler<32> read_32_handler_;

template<size_t S>
void initializeReadHandler(uint32_t begin,
                           uint32_t end,
                           ReadType<S> func) {
    begin >>= 16;
    end >>= 16;

    auto t = std::tie(read_8_handler_, read_16_handler_, read_32_handler_);
    for (uint32_t current = begin; current <= end; ++current) {
        auto& handler = std::get < ReadHandler<S>& >(t);
        handler[current & 0xFFFF] = func;
    }
}
```

Works like a charm :D  Thanks guys !

Comment: This looks fine to me, do you have any issues in particular with it?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to choose the correct array in the line in comment ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @max66's answer is great, if you want absolutely minimal code change you can do this in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).

This isn't required, but I like cleaning up the types:

```
template<class ReadType>
using handler_type = std::array<ReadType,   memory_handler_size>;
template<std::size_t S>
using handler_for_size = handler_type<ReadType<S>>;

handler_for_size<8> read_8_handler_;
handler_for_size<16> read_16_handler_;
handler_for_size<32> read_32_handler_;
```

and then `initializeReadHandler`:

```
template<size_t Size>
void initializeReadHandler(uint32_t begin,
                       uint32_t end,
                       ReadType<Size> func) {
  begin >>= 16;
  end >>= 16;
  for (uint32_t current = begin; current <= end; ++current) {
     auto& handler = std::get<handler_type<ReadType<Size>>( std::tie(read_8_handler_, read_16_handler_, read_32_handler_) );
     handler[current & 0xFFFF] = func;
  }
}
```

here we use type-based `get` and references to zero-cost get the right handler array.

The big difference is that you can leave your global `read_8_handler_` around.  If there isn't a reason for global `read_8_handler_`, use @max66's answer.

Comment: Intriguing use of `std::tie()`/`std::get()`. Anyway... I suppose that the optimizer make this automagically but... isn't better define/initialize `handler` outside the `for` loop? (and this is true also in my solution, I suppose...)

Comment: I think max66 has a point, I'll edit my question with the answer based on Quentin's, with some fixes ...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly and you wan't maintain `read_8_handler_`, `read_16_handler_` and `read_32_handler_` global variables (a sort of), I suppose you can wrap they as static variables inside template functions (heavily simplified following a Quentin's suggestion)

Something as

```
 template <std::size_t S>
 std::array<ReadType<S>, memory_handler_size> & getHandler () 
   { static std::array<ReadType<S>, memory_handler_size> h; return h; }
```

So you can use the deduced `Size` template parameter to select the requested function

```
template<size_t Size>
void initializeReadHandler(uint32_t begin,
                           uint32_t end,
                           ReadType<Size> func) {
    begin >>= 16;
    end >>= 16;

    auto & handler = getHandler<Size>();

    for (uint32_t current = begin; current <= end; ++current) {
       handler[current & 0xFFFF] = func;
    }
}
```

But, if possible, I suggest you to pass the array (by reference) as argument to the function.

Comment: Why the `struct` with a static function instead of a free fucntion template?

Comment: @Quentin - D'Oh! Because I was thinking about a solution struct based; I've modified it, modified it, modified it... there was an earthquake! A terrible flood! Locusts! IT WASN'T MY FAULT! (OK: you're right; simplified; thanks!)

Comment: Actually the arrays are private elements of a class, and I prefer using non static data for them ... so I'll stick with Quentin's solution ;)  But I learned from your post, so I'll upvote it :)

Comment: @Quentin : you're right, I fixed my mistake in the question, but I can't edit the comment apparently ... so that's free beer for you ;)